# Android, text within a TextView is partially invisible

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio Flamingo, trying to make a japanese dictionary app. I've got a TableLayout for the dictionary and TableRows for each word in it. Within that TableRows I've got two TextViews: one for original word, one for translation. The problem is, the first TextView should have bigger TextSize. Here is the simplified version:

```
public void init_words_list() throws IOException {
    TableLayout stk = findViewById(R.id.table_main);
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(com.google.android.material.R.attr.colorOnSecondary, typedValue, true);
    int text_color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, typedValue.resourceId);
    String[] dict = { "学", "learning, education" };
    double[] widths = { 0.6, 0.4 };
    int[] heights = { 30, 20 };
    TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(dict[i]);
        tv.setWidth((int) Math.round(widths[i] * (stk.getWidth())));
        tv.setTextSize(heights[i]);
        tv.setTextColor(text_color);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        tbrow.addView(tv);
    }
    stk.addView(tbrow);
}
```

This results in the second TextView being cut off. Like this:

[image]

I'm guessing, that the reason is the height of TextView being calculated before it is added to the row. However after being added, the first line in the second TextView is aligned with the first line in the first TextView. And because one is bigger than the other, an offset occurs. If I make first TextView's font smaller, the problem will resolve:

[image]

Unfortunately, I want it big. So, are there any workarounds for this problem?

UPD
Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/words_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: To answer your question, pls update your question with the layout file

Comment: @Ash There are several of them, I've added the one I modified.